# SQL Database "Operation must use an updateable query" Workaround

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

So my basic goal is to create a database for a shopsystem, which is my task to do for my IT course. I tried to create a UPDATE-Query, that collects all the Sale Positions ("tblPosition.PositionAnzahl") ordered with a SELECT-Query and groups it by the products ordered, to have an overview about how often each product has been sold.
I want to do this to keep track of how many items are still left in the inventory.
The Query was supposed to update 1 field ("tblArtikel.ArtikelVerkauft") in my table "tblArtikel", in which all my articles and their information is stored.

However, i just found out that you cannot run UPDATE-Queries, that use SELECT-Query data, as i get a error, that says "Operation must use an updateable query".

This is the code i used for the query:

```
UPDATE tblArtikel as a JOIN
       (SELECT p.PositionArtikelID, Sum(p.PositionAnzahl) AS SumOfPositionAnzahl
        FROM tblPositionen as p
        GROUP BY p.PositionArtikelID
       ) p
       ON a.ArtikelID = p.PositionArtikelID
    SET ArtikelVerkauft = p.SumOfPositionAnzahl;
```

Is there another way to keep track of all the Items left in my inventory, apart from doing what i did?

Here are screenshots of the 2 tables (the depending fields are circled red):

[tblPositionen with field PositionAnzahl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppdsB.png)

[tblArtikel with field ArtikelVerkauft](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOzKM.png)

I have not worked with SQL before and only learned about it during 45 min, so ther emight be an easy way for this, but i would still appreciate every answer from you guys.

Comment: You already have method to 'keep track' - the aggregate query, just don't go the extra step of saving to table. If it can be calculated for UPDATE it can be calculated when needed. Review http://allenbrowne.com/AppInventory.html. UPDATE query can be run that uses subquery, just not a subquery with aggregation. If you really MUST save, then use DSum() in query or VBA.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that actually helped me, since i was stuck there...
Is there a way to show that data in my Order form, so the customer sees how many products are in the inventory?

Comment: Expression use DSum in textbox is one way.